# AngularJS Directive with Filter and Color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, web-frontend

I have a list of the simple objects (containing only names) in my model:

```
var list = [{name: "Jane"}, {name: "Mary"}];
```

Here I display them:

```
<table>
<tr data-ng-repeat="pers in list | filter: filter.label >
<td >
{{pers.name }}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And that's fine.

I also have a filter:

```
Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
```

What I need to do is to mark the filtered match with some color: for example if you type "A" symbol it should display the search result: Mary, Jane where substring "A" will be red.
I guess I need to use the directives but I don't have much experience with them and I was wondering if somebody could advise how can I achieve this result?
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a simple task as it will require wrapping the matches in `<span>` tags. Yes it will involve using directive, regex and dom manipulation. Suggest you look for an existing highlighter directive. The scope of your question is too broad as it stands

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a filter to extract the matched search terms and replace them with  tag with your highlighting style.

```
<table>
<tr data-ng-repeat="pers in list | filter: filter.label" ng-bind-html="pers.name | highlight:filter.label">
<td >
{{pers.name }}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

your filter would look something like this:

```
.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(text, phrase) {
      if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
```

checkout this [demo](http://demo.codeforgeek.com/highlight-angular/)and the [code](https://github.com/codeforgeek/highlight-text-angular/blob/master/app.js)